# jquerymobile button's css not applied

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to add a delete button to a custom div. However when the page is loaded, the jquery mobile button does not take the format of jquery and displays it like a hyperlink.

```
var currDelButton = $("<a>").attr("href","#").attr("data-role","button").attr("data-icon","delete").attr("data-iconpos","left").text("حذف");
```

anyone has an idea about this issue?

Best Regards
Ali

Comment: What event is this wrapped in ? What's the code for your "page is loaded"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding the button after the page is loaded then you need to refresh the element for example `$("#mybutton").button();` should work.

here is a working example with the code you provided: http://jsfiddle.net/ashanova/RQVd8/1/

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. This was done in the pageshow event.

Comment: Can you explain the reason please

Comment: anything that is injected or dynamically created after pageinit event needs to be initialised

Answer (score 1):

call the `.page` for the main wrapper where new buttons are added.

```
$("#content").page();
```